# How do you pass data when using the navigate function in react router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In v4 you would do a history.push('/whatever', { data })
Then the component tied to that route could read the data object by referencing the history.location.state

Now with v6 that's changed to navigate('whatever')

How do you pass data like before?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's similar to how it's done in v4, two arguments, the second being an object with a `state` property.

```
navigate(
  'thepath',
  {
    state: {
      //...values
    }
  }
})
```

From the migration guide: [Use navigate instead of history](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/f59ee5488bc343cf3c957b7e0cc395ef5eb572d2/docs/advanced-guides/migrating-5-to-6.md#use-navigate-instead-of-history)

> If you need to replace the current location instead of push a new one
> onto the history stack, use `navigate(to, { replace: true })`. If you
> need state, use `navigate(to, { state })`. You can think of the first
> arg to navigate as your  and the other arg as the `replace`
> and `state` props.

To access the route state in the consuming component use the `useLocation` React hook:

```
const { state } = useLocation();
```

Comment: And how would you access it in the new navigated to component?

Comment: @user1663658 Route state will still be on the `location` object as far as I know, `const { state } = useLocation()`.

Comment: Thats what I would have thought, but no go.

        navigate({
            pathname: 'create',
            state: {
                duplicateLifecycle: duplicateLifecycle,
            },
        });
    let location = useLocation(); 
location.state is  null :/

Comment: @user1663658 Sorry, my initial response was incorrect, that was the v5 syntax. In v6 it would be `navigate('/create', { state: { duplicateLifecycle } })`, the target path is the first argument, a "config" object with state key is the second argument.

Comment: Yeo that did it. Honestly never seen the     state: { obj } syntax before

Comment: @user1663658 Ah, yeah, that is just object shorthand, useful when the object property you store uses the same name as the variable holding the value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions

Comment: Hi@DrewReese! How would you handle it if there was no data in the route state? I've encountered an issue where I get the error "Right side of assignment cannot be destructured". Here is the code: const { toast } = useLocation();
  const { autohide, toastVisible, error } = toast;      I use these three toast elements inside of a component on the same page

Comment: @cameronErasmus `toast` isn't a property on the `location` object. You probably need something more like `const { state } = useLocation()` then `const { toast } = state || {}`, *then* `const { autohide, toastVisible, error } = toast`. Does this make sense?

Comment: Perfect sense @DrewReese! Logical or is a perfect addition. Thanks for the tip!